# Selecting all the similar MAX values derived from COUNT()

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a simple MySQL table looks this:

```
    Table: Citizen

    Name    Country
    ----    ------
    Adam    USA
    Eva     Russia
    Arman   India
    Peter   USA
    Martin  Russia
    Jack    Finland
    Juno    Russia
    Fox     USA
    Maya    Finland
```

A simple query like

```
SELECT Country, COUNT(Name) People FROM Citizen  GROUP BY Country
```

will give me

```
Country     People
-------     ------
USA         3
Russia      3
Finland     2
India       1
```

**I want to find the Country with MAXIMUM number of people. In the case of a tie (i.e if two countries have the same number of max people), list all such country. The result table should look like this**

```
Country     MaxPeople
-------     ------
USA         3
Russia      3
```

I learned something about derived tables and came up with this query:

```
SELECT Country, MAX(TotCit) 
FROM (SELECT Country, COUNT(People) TotCit 
      FROM Citizen GROUP BY Country) 
AS CitTable
```

Which results in

```
Country   Max(TotCit)
-------   -----------
Finland   3
```

Any possible solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need all the countries, then the query is a bit cumbersome:

```
SELECT Country, COUNT(Name) as People
FROM Citizen 
GROUP BY Country
HAVING COUNT(Name) = (select max(cnt)
                      from (select COUNT(Name) as cnt
                            from Citizen
                            group by Country
                           ) c
                     );
```

The query does just what you are looking for.  The `HAVING` clause first calculates the counts for each country, then it calculates the `max()` and compares that to the aggregated value.

By the way, this is much easier in most other databases because they support window/analytic functions.

Answer (score 0):

The query by Gordon, simplified a bit.

- you don't need `COUNT(Name)`, unless `Nname` is a nullable column.
- the 2-nested subquery can be replaced with a simple subquery with `LIMIT`:

  ```
  SELECT Country, COUNT(*) AS People
  FROM Citizen 
  GROUP BY Country
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 
         ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS People
           FROM Citizen
           GROUP BY Country
           ORDER BY People DESC
           LIMIT 1
         ) ;
  ```

The condition in `HAVING` will probably lead to a very inefficient query, so you could rewrite as:

```
SELECT 
    g.Country, g.People
FROM
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS People
    FROM Citizen
    GROUP BY Country
    ORDER BY cnt DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS m
  JOIN
  ( SELECT Country, COUNT(*) AS People
    FROM Citizen  
    GROUP BY Country
  ) AS g
      ON g.People = m.People ;
```